# Issue with upgrading from JBOSS 7.1.1 to Wildfly 8.2.1

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly-8

In my project previously we were using jboss 7 as the application server and my application was having a code like below in the jboss-web.xml.

```
<jboss-web>
  <security-domain>my-form-auth</security-domain>
  <context-root>webapps</context-root>
  <valve>
    <class-name>com.session.MyAuthenticaor</class-name>
 </valve>
</jboss-web>
```

and it was working fine. But currently we upgraded to wildfly 8.2.1 and the valve is not getting called for any request.The valve is used for custom authentication. The valve code is like below.

package com.session;

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator;
import org.apache.catalina.connector.Request;
import org.apache.catalina.connector.Response;
import org.apache.catalina.deploy.LoginConfig;

public class MyAuthenticaor extends FormAuthenticator{

    public boolean authenticate(Request request, Response response,LoginConfig config) throws IOException {
        //code for authentication  
    }

}
```

Please help me with the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure the valve in standalone.xml file under web subsystem. as below

```
<valve name="<valve name>" module="<your valve module name>" class-name="com.session.MyAuthenticaor"></valve>
```